# Euler project #2

Tags: java

```
public class Fibonaccisequence {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int term[] = new int[]{1,2};
        int termValue = term[0]+term[1];
        int sum = 0;
        while(termValue <= 4000000)
        {
            termValue = term[0]+term[1];
            if (term[1]%2==0)
            {sum=sum+term[0];}


            int a= term[1];
            term[1]=termValue;
            term[0]=a;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
 }
```

Problem detail:
Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms

I got 2851443 as answer, and I checked my code many times.

Comment: What issue you are facing...?

Comment: @MehrajMalik the answer im getting is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem exists in this code:

```
if (term[1]%2==0)
{sum=sum+term[0];}
```

If you detect that term[1] is even, you should be adding it to the sum, not the previous value:

```
if (term[1] % 2 == 0) {
    sum = sum + term[1];  // add term[1], not term[0]
}
```